# Apply force to a specific point

Tags: python, game-engine, physics, force-fields

I would like to apply force to a specific point on the mesh. Could someone let me know how I can do that using Python scripting? The "applyForce" function applies the force to the center of the object. I need to apply the force to an arbitrary point.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [`applyImpulse`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75a_release/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject.applyImpulse).

> **applyImpulse(**point, impulse, local=False**)**
> Applies an impulse to the game object.
>
> This will apply the specified impulse to the game object at the specified point. If point != position, applyImpulse will also change the object’s angular momentum. Otherwise, only linear momentum will change.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to apply forces to soft body objects in no-BGE Blender as well? If so, could you please take a look at my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120655/how-to-make-an-interactive-two-finger-robot-gripper-and-grab-things-with-it) and post a solution?